# How do I assign IPv6 addresses manually?

Tags: networking, router, ipv6

So I'm still rather clueless with IPv6, but I wanted to try something with my network today. Currently, I assign IPv4 LAN addresses manually, so that my router is `192.168.0.1`, then my first computer is `192.168.0.2`, and so on.

So far, I haven't been able to figure out how to do this with IPv6. Or is the process completely different that this is not how it would work?

Router is an Archer C4000, and my main system runs Ubuntu 19.04

EDIT: To clarify with how I manually set network IP addresses, my router has a page where I can set an address of my choosing to a MAC address. No configuration is done outside of the router.

Comment: Please edit question and indicate **how** you assign LAN addesses manually. (On the router only? On your first computer as well?) I suspect you just set a network range on the router, and then addresses are **not** assigned "manually", but by DHCP from the router. On IPv6 then your router needs to advertise a subnet. On Ubuntu, you can set both IPv4 and IPv6 address manually with `ip addr add ...`.

Comment: Edited. I'm going to guess then that it is assigned from a range, but then I limit what can be assigned based on MAC addresses. If I'm setting the IP address manually on each device, is there any further configuration that needs to be done (apart from avoiding duplicates), or will the router just accept that device A is going to use its own configured address?

Comment: If there's a page where you can assign an IPv4 address based on a MAC address, then this is for static addresses assigned via DHCP from the router. IPv6 works differently. While there is DHCPv6, the normal way is to use [SLAAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Stateless_address_autoconfiguration), and let each computer pick an IPv6 address based on the announced subnet prefix.So this page won't help you to assign IPv6 addresses...

Answer (score 1):

> To clarify with how I manually set network IP addresses, my router has a page where I can set an address of my choosing to a MAC address. No configuration is done outside of the router

This usually isn't called "manual configuration" to avoid confusion (from the LAN hosts' point of view, it is still automatic configuration). The usual terms are "static DHCP lease" or "DHCP reservation".

---

Overall, the process in IPv6 is *usually* completely different.

In IPv6 primary address auto-configuration mechanism (SLAAC) is completely stateless: the router does not issue individual addresses; it only periodically advertises the subnet *address prefix* and each host just combines it with its own chosen suffix. The router cannot limit hosts to just a specific sub-range; in fact the router does not receive any feedback about hosts' chosen address at all.

(Depending on each device's OS, the suffix might be a MAC address in traditional RFC4862 SLAAC; it might be a static hash value in RFC7217; it might be completely random in RFC4941 "Privacy Extensions"; and it might even be a user-provided value if the OS allows that.)

For example, the router advertises `2001:db8:123:456::/64` as the LAN address prefix; client A combines it with its own MAC address and begins using `2001:db8:123:456:6af2:68fe:ff7c:e25c`.

---

That said, DHCP *does* exist in the IPv6 world and handles address leases in much the same way as IPv4 DHCP does. That means you can create DHCPv6 address pools, you can configure static address leases in DHCPv6, and so on. But not all clients support DHCPv6 at all (e.g. Android does not), so having SLAAC alongside is almost unavoidable.

So if you have a DHCPv6-capable client on a DHCPv6-capable network, chances are it'll have *both* a nice DHCPv6-assigned address and a longer SLAAC-autoconfigured address.

> If I'm setting the IP address manually on each device, is there any further configuration that needs to be done (apart from avoiding duplicates), or will the router just accept that device A is going to use its own configured address?

As you can see above, that's how IPv6 address configuration works *anyway*.

Answer (score 0):

Your router's manual is found in
[User Guide](https://static.tp-link.com/2018/201803/20180327/1910012258_Archer%20C4000(US)_V2_UG.pdf)
and contains for IPv6 only an option for entering a static IPv6 address
for the router itself (as received from the ISP).

The section about specifying the IP addresses that the router assigns by MAC
address does not say whether they are IPv4 or IPv6, but I think it is highly
unlikely that this will work for IPv6. And here is why.

IPv6 is quite unlike IPv4 in the sense that the long IPv6 address is made up of
two parts. The first (the prefix) is assigned by the ISP. The second is assigned
locally by the router or by each computer and is usually a random value based
on the MAC address.

This means that the router does not control the IPv6 prefix which the ISP
can change whenever it likes. You can force your computer to use a static IPv6
address, but only if it agrees with the ISP. You may be able to ask the ISP
for a static IPv6 address, but that is a bad idea.

The reason it's a bad idea, is that all your devices are visible to the entire
Internet by their IPv6 address (unless the router intervenes).
Therefore having a fixed IPv6 address just makes tracking you that much easier.

If you wish, you would in Windows set a computer's static IPv6 inside
*Start > Network > Network and Sharing Center > Change Adapter Setting*,
right-click on the Ethernet connection IPv6 and choose Properties,
right-click "Internet Protocol Version 6 (TCP/IPv6)" and click on Properties,
the set "Use the following IPv6 address".

But the fact you can does not mean you should.
The only place that static IPv6 addresses makes sense is inside a local
network which is not connected to the Internet.

Comment: What about if I wanted to run a web server? I'm constantly traveling for work, and I would love to have access to one of the computers at home which runs 24/7. I'd need to set a static IPv6 for this to work, wouldn't I?

Comment: A general solution would require an IPv6 dynamic DNS provider. See for that the article [dynv6.com: IPv6 dynamic DNS done right](https://patrakov.blogspot.com/2019/01/dynv6com-ipv6-dynamic-dns-done-right.html).

Comment: @harrymc Help me understand your logic, why would a server in a data center have a static IP but a server at home a dynamic one? In what world does that make any sense?

Comment: In a world where the ISP attributes to users dynamic IP addresses.